# win cmd: set /a value is reassigned on subsequent operations on %value%

Tags: windows, cmd, variable-assignment

Trying to run a one liner in Windows cmd (a take on the unix russian roulette):

> set /a nr=%random%*6/32768-0 & if %nr%==0 (echo lost) else (echo joy)

Yields, for ex:

> 0 joy
>
> 3 lost

Which makes no sense. So, adding an echo for %nr%:

> set /a nr=%random%*6/32768-0 & echo  "echo nr: %nr%" & if %nr%==0 (echo lost) else (echo joy)

Results in:

> 0 "echo nr: 3" joy
>
> 1 "echo nr: 0" lost

The question is obvious: why is the variable reassigned? (The reassignment occurs only once. If chained operations with %nr% are used, they will always use that reassigned value). Can someone please shed some light on this behavior? It went from annoying to baffling pretty damn quick.

Thanks, and a fine weekend end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch examines each line, replaces any `%var%` with the current value of that variable, then executes the resultant line, consequently, the `if` acts on the contents of the variable **before** it has a new value assigned.

please read any of the thousands of SO items related to `delayedexpansion` for solution strategies, the simples one of which is to use two separate lines

```
set /a nr=%random%*6/32768-0
if %nr%==0 (echo lost %nr%) else (echo joy %nr%)
```

or

```
set /a nr=%random%*6/32768-0
if %nr%==0 (
 echo lost %nr%
) else (
 echo joy %nr%
)
```

where the 5 lines of the `if` statement are regarded as one *logical* line.

You don't state whether you are executing the commands at the prompt or from a batch. That would have been good.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo for delayedexpansion, I'm looking over it now. It is still baffling (to me), and I'm still trying to figure out the logic behind it. Also, it wasn't a script, just a cmd prompt one liner (I thought the & chaining of commands was an indicator of that; which begs another question, shouldn't & or && wait for the complete execution of the previous command? I'll look into that on my own.) [Sidenote - I tried to upvote your answer, unfortunately I don't have enough stack cred]. All the best.

Comment: Batch always has first replaced vars, then executed the command. This has been maintained so that later versions execute old batches without changes.`delayedexpansion` is a later enhancement to allow `!var!` to be used to access the changing value of the variable as may be expected in higher-level languages. `&` is available in batches for chaining commands - but the *entire* logical line is still subject to the same sequence `%var%` is always replaced by its value first.